# When to use new Term Group rather than creating new Term Set

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, term-store, term-set

Can anyone adivce when i need to create a new term group and when i need to create a new term set ?

In my case i have a term set named "Standard" that contain some ISO standards terms. and i am referencing this term set inside some managed metadata columns. now i have created a new site collection and i need to create a new term set also named "Standard" which contain  software development standards rather than ISo standards. so i created a new term group and i add the new term set "standards" to it... so my question is when i should create a new term group over creating new term sets ,, other than the reason i mentioned which is to have the same term set name used twice ?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groups define security boundaries. A group is a set of term sets that all share common security requirements. Only users who are designated as contributors to a specific group can manage term sets that belong to the group or create new term sets within it. **Organizations should create unique groups for term sets that will have unique access or security needs.**

In your case, i dont think you have anyother choice then creating a new group, Unless you want to change the name of `termset` i.e Standards or _Standard etc.

Comment: thanks . so security is the factor that i will decide whether to create a new group or not ?and are there other factors to consider  ?

Comment: Security is the main thing, but also you can use groups to "declutter" if you have a lot of term sets, by categorizing the term sets in different term groups)